# Adding a print out message to count in loop (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

With 'range' is it possible to add a print out message when the count hits a number in the range:

Starting with this:

```
for number in range(0,11):

   print(number)
```

Comment: If you can ask the question properly, you have solved 75% of the problem. Try a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

```
for number in range(0, 11):
    if number == 6: #the number in the range
        print(f'Number has hit {number}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Turn that question into pseudocode. Let's say `7` is your target number.

```
for number in range between 0,11
if number equals my target number
print out that number
```

With that rational, it might be something like this:

```
for number in range(0,11):
 if(number == 7):   
   print("here is the target number: ", number)
```

Comment: `if` is not a function, so you don't need the parentheses. `if(number == 7):` should be `if number == 7:`. And if you follow the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) further you should do the indentation with 4 spaces per level.